# defining optional attribute in AWS Api Gateway -> DynamoDB mapping

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I'm following along: [Using Amazon API Gateway as a proxy for DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-api-gateway-as-a-proxy-for-dynamodb/)

Taking the blog's example, I want to tighten what and how data is written to a dynamodb table frontend by Api Gateway. To this end I define the following mapping in Api Gateway:

```
{ 
    "TableName": "Comments",
    "Item": {
      "commentId": {
        "S": "$context.requestId"
       },
       "pageId": {
         "S": "$input.path('$.pageId')"
       },
       "userName": {
         "S": "$input.path('$.userName')"
       },
       "message": {
         "S": "$input.path('$.message')"
       }
    }
}
```

Following along, testing with the following example works just fine:

```
{
  "pageId": "breaking-news-story-01-18-2016",
  "userName": "Just Saying Thank You",
  "message": "I really enjoyed this story!!"
}
```

However, let's say I want to keep the same mapping as above but want to make `message` optional. How would I do that? I can't get it to work. I've tried:

1. using the above mapping as is, but sending a body without the `message`-attribute. --> "One or more parameter values were invalid: An AttributeValue may not contain an empty string"
   2 using the above mapping as is, but sending a body with `message=null`. --> "One or more parameter values were invalid: An AttributeValue may not contain an empty string"
2. changing above mapping by omitting the definition for `mapping` -> passing a body now without `message` succeeds obviously. However, sending a body with `message` doesn't pass `message` through (which is what I expected, but wanted to exhaust all options)
3. Don't use a mapping at all. Obviously that works, but now everything is passed-through unfiltered, which is unwanted.

Obviously I could use AWS lambda instead to do the mapping but this feels like such a common use-case, i.e.: optional attributes, that this must be possible directly in Api Gateway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Courtesy of @ka:

Explatation: APi gateway auto-populates non-existing attributes with empty strings or something. This needs to be excluded from the if.

Also notice the critical `,` right after the if statement.

```
{ 
    "TableName": "Comments",
    "Item": {
      "commentId": {
        "S": "$context.requestId"
       },
       "pageId": {
         "S": "$input.path('$.pageId')"
       },
       "userName": {
         "S": "$input.path('$.userName')"
       }#if($input.path('$.description') && $input.path('$.message') != ""),
       "message": {
         "S": "$input.path('$.message')"
       }
       #end
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind trying this mapping template? If the message is NULL, it will not be added to the body.

```
{ 
    "TableName": "Comments",
    "Item": {
      "commentId": {
        "S": "$context.requestId"
       },
       "pageId": {
         "S": "$input.path('$.pageId')"
       },
       "userName": {
         "S": "$input.path('$.userName')"
       }#if ($.message),
       "message": {
         "S": "$input.path('$.message')"
       }
       #end
    }
}
```

Thanks,
-Ka Hou

Comment: Sadly that doesn't work: `Execution failed due to configuration error: Unable to transform request`

Comment: Got it to work. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. See my answer